# script para inserir formula

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, fórmula

Bem, eu bolei um script para verificar se uma coluna contem uma formula, e, se n'ao contiver, ele insere. Estou fzendo isso pq toda vez que eu preencho um formulario, a formula que estava antes na celula some. Logo, o script vai executar de hora em hora, verificar se a formula foi apagada e, caso sim, ele a insere novamente. Bem, me script e esse? Porem, nao esta funcionando, embora nao acuse nenhum erro, a formula nao aparece na coluna como deveria.
OBS: se eu por as aspas duplas, da um erro de: ~Falta ; antes da declaração. (linha 13, arquivo "insereFormula"). A linha 13 e essa: prazo = "=IF(COUNTA(E4)=0;"";E4-TODAY())"; 
      Entao, eu deixei aspas simples mesmo.

```
function myFunction() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 0;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, numRows-startRow,lastCol).getValues();  //Get all values except the header rows


  for (var i=0;i<numRows-startRow;i++){ 
  var prazo = dataRange[i][8];
    if (prazo == '') {
     prazo = '=IF(COUNTA(E4)=0;"";E4-TODAY())'; 

    }
  }
}
```